# how a specific qr code open specific activity in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, qr-code

hey I am a beginner in android studio, i created a specific qr code and i 
    want to link it a specific activity , means (the result of one text qr code open once specific activity)  i want that qr code open this
     specific activity. for example i have qr code with the world hello i want to link this word link to an `helloactivity`. is that possible?
    and idk how to code it.

```
if theres any example related please post it
 thank you

android studio

@Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        final String myResult = result.getText();
        Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getText());
        Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getBarcodeFormat().toString());

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(MainActivity.this);
            }
        });
        builder.setNeutralButton("Visit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myResult));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });
        builder.setMessage(result.getText());
        AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
        alert1.show();
```

none

I

Comment: Well what's the result of result.getText() line code? do you know how to call other activities?

Comment: nothing it stays blank and 
no I don't sorry , I am a beginner in android, idk how to call a text in qr code , I want the text from qr code when it scan open an specific activity